# barplot xlim shifts axis -> offset to axis at=midpoints missing

Tags: bar-chart, axis, offset

I have the following problem – it is purely an ascetic one but it bothers me that it is not looking nicely: 
I generate a simple sideways barplot with ticks at the bottom of the bars. The default setting generates an x-axis which is shorter than my bars (figure 1). To solve this I included xlim. Once I do that the x-axis is slightly shifted to the left so the y-axis is touching the bars (figure 2). This does not look nice at all. I guess xlim somehow overwrite a default parameter but I could not find which. I would be grateful for any suggestions!

```
rm(list=ls())


data<-c(69,500,597)
names(data)<-c("text1", "text2", "text3")

midpoints<-barplot(data, beside=T, space=1, xlim=c(0,600))

filename=paste("orig.pdf", sep="")
pdf(file=filename, width=10, height =5)

par(mar=c(4,9,1,4))
barplot(data, beside=T, xlab=expression(paste("Text")), 
        axes=T, cex.lab=2, cex.axis=2, cex.names=2,  font.axis = 2,
        col=c("grey"),  horiz=T, las=1, font.lab=2,  space=1, 
        names.arg=colnames(data))
axis(side = 2, at = midpoints , labels = F, cex.axis=1.5)


dev.off()

filename=paste("with_limit.pdf", sep="")
pdf(file=filename, width=10, height =5)

lim<-c(0,600)
par(mar=c(4,9,1,4))
barplot(data, beside=T, xlab=expression(paste("Text")), 
        axes=T, cex.lab=2, cex.axis=2, cex.names=2,  font.axis = 2,
        col=c("grey"),  horiz=T, las=1, font.lab=2,  space=1, 
        names.arg=colnames(data), xlim=lim)
axis(side = 2, at = midpoints , labels = F, cex.axis=1.5)


dev.off()
```

Figure 1
[image]
Figure 2
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I did find two possible answers both not perfect but working.
The first one is to work with xaxs="r" but for my taste now the offset is too large.

```
filename=paste("solution1.pdf", sep="")
pdf(file=filename, width=10, height =5)

lim<-c(0,600)
par(mar=c(4,9,1,4))
barplot(data, beside=T, xlab=expression(paste("Text")), 
        axes=T, cex.lab=2, cex.axis=2, cex.names=2,  font.axis = 2,
        col=c("grey"),  horiz=T, las=1, font.lab=2,  space=1, 
        names.arg=colnames(data), xlim=lim, xaxs="r")
axis(side = 2, at = midpoints , labels = F, cex.axis=1.5)


dev.off()
```

[Solution1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llrhh.png)

The second option is to have xlim starting in the negative. This has the disadvantage of tuning the offset by hand. In my case I had multiple figures and I wanted it always to be the same so I used (here) 2% of the maximum 600 -> 12. For all others I also used 2% of the maximum. That worked nicely in the end.

```
filename=paste("solution2.pdf", sep="")
pdf(file=filename, width=10, height =5)

lim<-c(-12,600)
par(mar=c(4,9,1,4))
barplot(data, beside=T, xlab=expression(paste("Text")), 
        axes=T, cex.lab=2, cex.axis=2, cex.names=2,  font.axis = 2,
        col=c("grey"),  horiz=T, las=1, font.lab=2,  space=1, 
        names.arg=colnames(data), xlim=lim)
axis(side = 2, at = midpoints , labels = F, cex.axis=1.5)


dev.off()
```

[Solution2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48VXb.png)